# How to reopen ViewPart?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am working to make an Eclipse Plugin. I used a plugin project template that generated a View class which extends ViewPart. I think that it is part of SWT.

My problem is that the View is like a window inside of the main Frame which has buttons for close, minimize. I clicked on the X button of the View by mistake. Now I cannot make it visible again even if I relaunch the Eclipse Application.

Now, my Eclipse application looks like this:

[image]

It had some panels and buttons before. But I cannot make the View visible again. How should I make to bring it back? I have tried to delete the plugin project from Eclipse and import it again. But it did not work.

I bet that there it is an easy way to make the View visible again but I do not know how. Is there any setting through MANIFEST file? Or other file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the `-clearPersistedState` argument when you run the RCP (this assumes you are using Eclipse 4.x).

Comment: Worked very fine! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

1) quick solution
 restart workbench with clear workspace option checked under run configuration ..

2) Full Solution
you should add a menu in menu bar to open your view so that you can open your view when ever you want

create a command say openMyMenu
create a handler for it and call below code from handler execute method.
add that command to main menu bar..

```
 PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().showView(<view ID>);
```